# subscribing to multiple observable while keeping reference to function parameters

Tags: rxjs, angular8, angular9, rxjs-pipeable-operators, rxjs-observables

I have an input of a string array for Enums I want to recieve from server:

```
enumList = ['somethin','branch','country', 'serviceType', 'thatandthis'];
```

I then have a generic http-service method that takes an **enumList** string as a parameter and returns an HttpClient observable for that Enum service:

```
this.webApi.getEnumByName('somethin','en').subscribe((res)=>{/*do something*/})
this.webApi.getEnumByName('branch','en').subscribe((res)=>{/*do something*/})...
```

I'm than combining the two into a loop

```
   for (const item of this.enumList) {
      this.webApi.getEnumByName(item).subscribe((res: any) => {
          this.enums[item] = res;
      });
    }
```

But this is not good...
I want the a subscription that completes only once when all subscriptions has resolved, while keeping a reference to the associated **item string** 

using an array of observables returned from this.webApi.getEnumByName(item), **concat or forkJoin won't work because they won't keep refference to the associated string/key/token of the response** e.g the string in the enumList.

The end result of these concatinated observables should be:

```
{
    'somethin':{respopnse...},
    'branch':{respopnse...},
    'country':{respopnse...},
    'serviceType':{respopnse...},
    'thatandthis':{respopnse...}
}
```

breaking my head on this will appriciate an rxjs solution

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function to pass in this.enumList and still getting the same reference

```
function getResponse(enum){
  return forkJoin(....).subscribe(....)
}
```

or

forkjoin this.enumList with http call list

```
forkJoin(of(this.enumList), forkJoion(httpcall1,htttpcall2))
.subscribe([enum,responsesArray]=>....)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right your problem, you may want to consider something like this.

First of all you build an Observable with a function like this

```
function obsFromItem(item) {
   return this.webApi.getEnumByName(item).pipe(
      tap(res => this.enums[item] = res),
   )
}
```

The above logic says that as soon as `getEnumByName` notifies its result, than the result is set into `this.enums` at the right item.

Now that you have a similar function, you can create an array of Observables to be passed  into `forkJoin` like this

```
arrayOfObs = enumList.map(item => obsFromItem(item))
forkJoin(arrayOfObs).subscribe()
```

When `forkJoin(arrayOfObs)` notifies, it means that all the Observables built via `obsFromItem` have emitted and therefore `this.enums` should be rightly filled.

`forkJoin` gives you parallel execution. If you substitute `forkJoin` with `concat` you get sequential execution.

[In this article](https://medium.com/better-programming/rxjs-patterns-emerging-from-stackoverflow-asynchronous-api-calls-as-streams-in-the-real-world-ef636c9af19a) you may find some typical patterns of use of Obaservables with http calls.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine several observables together like that:

```js
forkJoin(enumList.reduce<any>((result, key) => {
  result[key] = this.webApi.getEnumByName(key,'en');
  return result;
}, {})).subscribe(allTogether => {
  // allTogether.somethin;
  // allTogether.branch;
  // ...
});
```